# Specify page size in jquery datatable server side pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, server-side

I have a datatable which uses server side pagination with infinite scroll. So my pages loads as an when I scroll down the table. Now the default page size is 10. How can I override this number?
I tried setting iDisplayLength:50, but didnt work.

```
ListDataTable= $("#ListDataPane_data").dataTable({
                 "iDisplayLength":50,
                "bFilter": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sServerMethod": "POST",
                "sAjaxSource": ListResourcePaginationUrl,
                "bProcessing": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "bJQueryUI": false,
                "bDestroy": true,



                 "bScrollInfinite": true,
                 "sScrollY": "300px",
                 "sScrollX": "963px",
                 "fnServerParams": function (aaData) {
                    aaData.push(
                     { "name": "Status", "value": status}
                    );

                    });
                },
```

Please help.

Comment: Please provide some code. It's probably right to change a variable but it's hard to say which one.

Comment: There you go.. I have pasted the code

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the [server doesn't respect](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/11665/idisplaylength-not-limiting-records./p1) the iDisplayLength value. In this case you must also update the server side.

Comment: I have checked the server side code.. am reading the value as it comes. Not changing anything there..

Answer (score 0):

"iDisplayLength":50 works, I just had to clear the browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

you should call fnDraw method in DataTable after change iDisplayLength field value: 
   table.fnSettings().iDisplayLength  = 20;
and 
   table.fnDraw();